# Thread re-purpose

Tags: multithreading

Can we re-purpose the completion port thread (for async I/O operation) as worker thread in CLR process ThreadPool ?

If this is naïve then can someone suggest me how to maximize the use of thread pool threads in order to reduce number of work item stacked in the worker queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IOCP threads are already sorta 'workers' - they take input from a queue and act on the received items.  If you wish to avoid using another thread pool for processing items other than 'normal' IOCP completion objects rx from the network drivers, there is nothing stopping you from 'manually' queueing up objects to the IOCP queue that ask the IOCP pool threads to perform other actions.  I forget the actual APIs now, but AFAIK there should be no problem.

I remember using such a mechanism for server tuning - reducing the number of IOCP threads by queueing an item that instructed the receiving IOCP pool thread to terminate.

That said, I'm not sure that such a mechansim will improve throughput significantly - the work has to be done somewhere and it may be that avoiding an extra thread pool would not help much.  Empirically, as a general-purpose inter-thread comms mechanism, an IOCP queue has a worse performance than Windows message queues, (useless for thread pools anyway since only one thread can wait), and user-space CS/semaphore-based P-C queues.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your support. Even i heard about the proposed approach. But I am stuck and not getting enough progress after googling.